# Read from device file

Tags: c, kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a kernel module myModule with major number 100 and minor number 120.
Here is what I did:

```
make all
sudo insmod ./myModule.ko
mknod ~/myModule c 100 120
```

When I check the log with

```
cat /proc/syslog
```

then it shows the printk() things from the init function.

But I have also implemented this function:

```
ssize_t myModule_read(struct file *f, char __user *user_buffer, size_t num, loff_t *offset);
```

It provides a printk() when a process reads from the device file.
Since my device file is in my home directory, I tried the following:

```
cat ~/myModule
```

and

```
hexdump ~/myModule
```

but it said that there is no such device or address.

How can I actually trigger the read (or release) function then?

EDIT:
In case the mknod was redundant: the device file is also not in the /dev/ directory.
But it shows up with:

```
cat /proc/devices
```

Comment: Is your home directory mounted with the `nodev` option?

Comment: Not that I know of. It worked with a different device though.
But since we are at it: Did I actually have to create the device file with mknod or is this redundant?

Comment: I don't know of any way other than `mknod` to do that on Linux, but there might be one.  Post your device registration code.

Comment: Here the registration, allocation and the hanging in:
deviceNumber = MKDEV(MAJOR, MINOR);
register_chrdev_region(deviceNumber, 1, "myModule");
myDevice = cdev_alloc();
cdev_add(myDevice, deviceNumber, 1);

Comment: Are you using a filled-in `file_operations` struct, and setting the `ops` field of the `cdev` struct you get from `cdec_alloc()`?  If you're doing all that, something strange is going on.

Comment: static struct file_operations fops = { .read = myModule_read, .open = myModule_open, .release = myModule_release,}; Nothing else. If you know what is going on, please write an answer so I can give you a check mark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79821/discussion-between-johannes-klaus-and-andrew-henle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure you're setting the the `struct file_operations *ops` field of the `cdev` structure returned from `cdev_alloc()`:

```
myModule->ops = &fops;
```